# How to run a playbook and pointing to the different but new defined groupvar?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

To keep this short, I'm a beginner in Ansible, just wanted to know how can someone run the playbook and point to the new `groupvar` and `hostvar` file?

For instance, I have some variables set in *all.yml* and would like to run new set of variables on *all1.yml*.

What's the best way to do it without affecting other variables?

Comment: For now your question is quite unclear. What are *all.yml* and *all1.yml*? Inventories files? Variables files that you load in a playbook? What are the variables in those files (the same but with different values, different variables, ...)?

Comment: So my objective is to run a playbook to against the 2nd set of variables defined in other .yml. How can i do that?

Comment: You are still not replying the vague part of your question. What you should really do is to show us what you have right now (how do you work with *all.yml*) and then from there, someone might be able to help you. See what is a [mre] and [ask].

Comment: Example:

When I run playbook: ansible-playbook -i inventory installabc.yml, I wanted to point the variables I defined in all.yml for installabc.yml to other yml file.

Comment: I don't know what code you need, I just need to know how, don't know what code you want me to show you. Variables like ds_password:xxxxxxxx or {{ ldap_binddn_password }}

Comment: Please do not spread the necessary info to understand your question over volatile comments: [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65443452/edit) instead. Don't give a vague and approximate description of what you are trying to do: listen to  β.εηοιτ.βε comment, read the links he kindly provided and show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as he asked.

Answer (score 0):

The all.yml file is setting variables for the all inventory group (this group is available by default and includes all hosts defined on your inventory file).

If you set variables in group_vars/all1.yml, you'll automatically get those variables on hosts defined on the all1 group, so just create an inventory group named all1 with your host.

Comment: Thank you, so how do i have my Playbook point to group_vars/all1.yml ? Thank you very much Richard! Merry Xmas!

Comment: You can put "hosts: all1" on your playbook to run it on the all1 group. That will automatically load variables defined in group_vars/all1.yml.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard I will give it a shot!